# Domaining with PHP

Tags: php, dns, subdomain

I have a site say abc.com and a user account is accessed at abc.com/user. Now I want to add functionality that user can link his site say user.com to abc.com/user. Can u please give me an overview that how this process can be done dynamically via php?

Comment: Adding a GET flag? `abc.com/user?user=blah` to make it display user 'blah'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set up DNS to point the host name at the server
2. Set up the server configuration so the site is the default virtual host (so if an unrecognised domain name is used to request it, the right site will be loaded)
3. Use `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` instead of the path.

Comment: All domains will point to same server... How to differentiate domains for different users?

Comment: @user1871640 — Read step 3 again

Comment: ok thanks... can u refer me some site/tutorial for in depth clarification

Comment: What sort of depth do you need? You get `user.com` out of the variable. You can then look that up in your database to figure out what user it is associated with and display the appropriate content.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly - you want that a person who is entering user.com will see the content from abc.com/user.

I would recommend checking out `launchrock.com` they do exactly this, and it involves adding a CNAME dns record as I remember, another way to do this is to create a Proxy flag rule in httpd (mod_proxy must be enabled for this), so that you won't have to restart the server, you can always the .htaccess in your www dir.

doing so dynamically will be easy if you go the proxy route, as you just need to append a new proxypass every time a new site is deployed, or create a parameterized rule, like a regular htaccess, as far as automating DNS records creation, I'm sure that's possible and maybe DNS provider such as godaddy or AWS have api for those kinds of things, but more research is required.